# I am getting a invalid parameter error on a Http Post request from a java client

Tags: java, ssl, http-post

I am making HTTP Post requests from a pojo java application on the IBM I-series server.

```
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I am getting this error back after about 3 seconds.

```
java.net.SocketException: A system call received a parameter that is not 
valid. (Read failed)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:127)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:182)      
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)      
at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:192)                                    
     at com.ibm.jsse2.b.a(b.java:168)                                     
     at com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:358)                                   
     at com.ibm.jsse2.at.i(at.java:785)                                   
     at com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:68)                                    
     at com.ibm.jsse2.at.startHandshake(at.java:520)                      
     at 
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredS
ocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)                                   
     at 
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(
SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)                                         
     at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.conn
ect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)                            
     at 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.conne
ct(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)                              
     at 
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainC
lientExec.java:380)                                                          
     at 
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientEx
ec.java:236)                                                                 
     at 
org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.j
```

I have made sure we are using TLS 1.2 and java version is 1.8

Client side - code snippets -

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = 

HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://lb1.cardknox.com/gateway");

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Note:
It works fine when I use it from my eclipse workbench - I only have the issue when I run this on the IBM server.

Java runtime details on the IBM server
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3280sr4fp10-20170727_01(SR4 FP10))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 OS/400 ppc-32 jvmap3280sr4fp10-20170727_01 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_20170722_0201_B357405
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20170722_357405
GC   - R28_20170722_0201_B357405
J9CL - 20170722_357405)
JCL - 20170726_01 based on Oracle jdk8u144-b01

Answer (score 0):

IBM Websphere server use IBM JRE not Oracle JRE. Here is the quote.

> The IBM implementation of SSLContext.getInstance("TLS") is different
>   from the Oracle implementation.

Find below the link for this.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/sslcontext.html.

Also look into the following quotes

> If you set the system property com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS=true
>   and you enable either SP800-131a strict compliance
>   (com.ibm.jsse2.sp800-131) or Suite B (com.ibm.jsse2.suiteB) system
>   properties, only the TLS V1.2 protocol is enabled.

from the below link.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/matchsslcontext_tls.html

Reference Links
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.71.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/protocols.html

Comment: We are not using IBM Websphere, but native java SE 8 install on the IBM I-server. I'm not sure if it helps - but we are doing this already...
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

Comment: Can you check the java version in IBM Server and let us know.

Comment: I just added it to the top thread as it was larger than what the comments allowed - can you please refer to the main post above ?

Comment: Yes, it is visible that it is IBM JRE version 1.8, can you try with this link.https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/SSL-handshake-fails-due-to-TLSv1-used-on-IBM-JDK

Comment: Did you try by setting the system property as given in the above link ?

Comment: Hi Sambit, yes we have tried it and it did not help. 
Since we were using Java 8 we thought its default - we did set the system setting like you advised.

Comment: Could you plz check, I have updated and let me know.